# Is the Higgs field stronger in the presence of mass?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, density

An EM field from a transmitter is stronger at the source than a light-year away. A magnetic field is stronger at the magnet than 1000 km away. A gravitational field is stronger near the mass than further away.

I am wondering if the Higgs field might also be stronger (or denser?) where it "sources" mass.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: The terms "denser " or "stronger" have no definition that I know of in this context, since the analogy with classical fields like volumetric mass or volumetric charge doesn't work with quantum fields. Unless the author states the exact definition of those terms, I don't think any scientifically sound answer is possible.

Comment: @Miyase, see edits to understand my thought process behind the question. Maybe you answered the question if the fields I mentioned are what you meant by "analogy with classical fields".

Comment: @drC1Ron, all of my questions have been down voted lately with very little feedback on what's wrong with them. I'm thinking this site is more for experts who have questions rather than enthusiastic amateurs.

Comment: @CramerTV you have misunderstood what the Higgs field is. It is not like an electric or a magnetic field. Instead it is a quantum field, and these are altogether stranger objects than the types of fields we are used to in everyday life. The problem is that understanding quantum fields requires several years of a physics degree and it isn't possible a simple explanation of them without excessive oversimplification.

Comment: @JohnRennie, thank you John for that explanation. I have read, admired, and mostly understood your answers for many years. And I think you are being generous in your wording that I "misunderstand" what a Higgs Field is - we both know I have ZERO understanding of what it is. ;) But simply saying, as Miyase also pointed out, that, no, classical fields are completely different animals than quantum fields with no analogous parts, answers my question and teaches me something.

Comment: @CramerTV the site is aimed at *active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy* as discussed in [the tour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember that downvotes are not a personal criticism. They mean only that a question is not a good fit for the site. Enthusiastic amateurs are welcome, but you may find your questions being downvoted if we don't think they are suitable for the site. The best place to discuss things like this is in [the Physics SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). You can ask anything there.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I appreciate that and don’t take offense at downvotes. As I noted, downvotes without explanation are what I find unhelpful. This question the comments were useful to help clarify. Other questions the comments were used to disparage me personally which I do take offense to. That is not in the spirit of the website, imho. Lastly, while I am not a student in the formal sense, I think most of us on this site continue to study physics and learn more. Thanks for the link, I did not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs field is a Lorentz scalar, which is unusual. It exists everywhere with the same value. If you rotate, it looks unchanged, and if you boost yourself to 99.9999% $c$, it looks the same. Very counter intuitive, esp with Lorentz contraction and Time dilation going on.